# Font size rendering is different depending upon login using Gimp?

Tags: linux, plugins, gimp, rc, gimpfu

I am using Gimp python-fu plugin. The plug-in written correctly renders a text block:

```
(GIMP_UNIT_POINT = 3)
titleBlockLayer = pdb.gimp_text_layer_new(img, title, <font_name>, 40, GIMP_UNIT_POINT)
```

but only if gimp is invoked from the X window manager (or a terminal window) when logged in on the computer's console (Fedora, various releases, same behavior; various releases of GIMP, same behavior). 
However, when logged in via ssh, (using X11 forwarding to display locally), the fonts are rendered HUGE by comparison.

I am confused because (supposedly) the same login .profile and .rc files have been run regardless.

Does anyone have a clue as to what/where/how GIMP determines what a POINT means, because it is obviously not coded in but dependent upon some resource file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Gimp a point is 1/72 of an inch, according to the doc of `gimp_text_get_extents_fontname()` in the PDB browser:

> If you need to display a font in points, divide the size in points by 72.0 and multiply it by the vertical resolution of the image you are taking into account.

Experimentally, when using points in `gimp_text_layer_new()` the size depends on the image print definition. This value can depend on user settings (72DPI by default) but you can control/set it using  `gimp_image_get_resolution(...)` and `gimp_image_set_resolution(...)`. What bothers me though it that it seems that at least on my Ubuntu 16.04 `gimp_text_layer_new()` works in inches and not in points (at 72DPI, points and pixels should be equivalent), so I would stick to using pixels and to the point<->pixels conversions using the image resolution.

Btw, what are the versions of Gimp and the Pango and Cairo libs on your various systems?

Edit: Possible explanation: it appears that in recent versions (since 2.8 at least), `gimp_text_layer_new()` accepts more than units than just pixels and points. It also takes millimeters, inches, and picas. So it's no longer `0` for pixels and `1` for points, and you can use the predefined `UNIT_*` values. The catch: `1` is no longer the value for points but is now the value for inches:

```
UNIT_PIXEL=0
UNIT_INCH=1 
UNIT_MM=2
UNIT_POINT=3
UNIT_PICA=4
```

Comment: workstation: gimp 2.8.14 / pango 1.36.8-1 / pangomm 2.34.0-4 / cairo 1.14.2-1

Comment: workstation: gimp 2.8.14 / pango 1.36.8-1 / pangomm 2.34.0-4 / cairo 1.14.2-1
server: gimp 2.6.11 / pango 1.26 / Fontconfig 2.7.3 / cairo 1.8.8-3

Thanks for the hint.  I'm going to try to force the resolution at the beginning of the scripts and see what happens when I remote-in from a laptop.  Chrys

Comment: @ChrysG 2.6.11: 10/2010, 2.8.14: 08/2014: 4 years, many things could change (and current Gimp is 2.10.12...).

Comment: gimp_image_set_resolution() was the key for using UNIT_POINT sizes. just force every image to a particular resolution at the beginning of the script -- Otherwise, use pixel math everywhere.